# Error opening Oracle connection on server-ORA-3134

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle

I am developing an application in ASP.NET which at the time of publishing the application and subsequently wanting to log in makes a connection to the Oracle database **(Oracle 9i)**, when it tries to open the connection it sends me an error message which says the following:

> **ORACLE.DATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLEEXCEPTION ORA-3134**: CONNECTIONS TO THIS 
>   SERVER VERSION ARE NO LONGER SUPPORTED.    AT 
>   ORACLE.DATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLEEXCEPTION.HANDLEERRORHELPER(INT32 ERRCODE, 
>   ORACLECONNECTION CONN, INTPTR OPSERRCTX, OPOSQLVALCTX* POPOSQLVALCTX, 
>   OBJECT SRC, STRING PROCEDURE, BOOLEAN BCHECK)
>   AT ORACLE.DATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLEEXCEPTION.HANDLEERROR(INT32 ERRCODE, 
>   ORACLECONNECTION CONN, INTPTR OPSERRCTX, OBJECT SRC)
>   AT ORACLE.DATAACCESS.CLIENT.ORACLECONNECTION.OPEN()

**I have installed on the server, ODAC 11.2 Release 5 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (11.2.0.3.20) 32bit**
It should be clarified that when running locally on my computer it does it without problems. With the same client installed.

which makes me strange because I created a console application that makes the connection to the same database and if it runs smoothly on the server where I am publishing the project and if it brings me records. Could you help me solve this problem.
This is the DLL that I use for both the one I do in the console and for the web project. I am even using the same method in both applications.

[image]


This is the information from the Oracle database that I want to connect to

> Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.7.0 - Production
>     PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.7.0 - Production
>     "CORE 9.2.0.7.0   Production"
>     TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.2.0.7.0 - Production
>     NLSRTL Version 9.2.0.7.0 - Production

Comment: What do you mean by "Oracle 9i"? Version 9.2.0 or 9.0.1?

Comment: hi @WernfriedDomscheit this is mi Oracle Database: 
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.7.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.7.0 - Production
"CORE 9.2.0.7.0 Production"
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.2.0.7.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 9.2.0.7.0 - Production

Comment: Are you running a 32 bit or 64 bit application?

Comment: Hi @jdweng In my app web and console application in the configuration is "Any CPU"

Comment: Have a look at https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=207303.1 - in general it should work, however you are at the "edge" of supported combinations.

Comment: When you compile at "Any CPU" then it runs on 64-bit (as I assume your Windows is 64-bit nowadays) but you installed 32-bit Oracle. Are you sure you don't have a (higher version) 64-bit Oracle Client installed. Verify which DLL is actually loaded with `Connection.GetType().Assembly.Location`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have a 12.2.0 client installed on the server, but other applications refer to that client or can I uninstall the 12.2.0 client and still the other applications would still work with the 11.2 client?

Comment: Check the Interoperability matrix above from link. Important point is: A 64-it application requires the 64-bit Oracle Client, a 32-bit application requires the 32-bit Oracle Client. You cannot mix it (unless you use the ODP.NET Managed Driver, however this can connect only to Oracle 11.2 or newer .)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle.DataAccess assembly error when I publish the project on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756347/oracle-dataaccess-assembly-error-when-i-publish-the-project-on-the-server)