# Oracle.DataAccess assembly error when I publish the project on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, server

This is my case, I have the **Oracle 11.2.0.3.0 64-bit client installed**, when I add in the project the Oracle.DataAccess dll that comes in the Oracle ado.Net folder and compile the project on my machine if it works for me. Therefore, when I publish the project on the server, where I also install the same client that I have installed on my machine, the project does not work for me, it sends me an error message:
I have to use this version of Oracle to connect to an old version of Oracle **(Oracle 9i).**

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

> [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
>      System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
>      System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +736
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +284
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +521
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9969128
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254

I already tried publishing the project as"**Any CPU**", "**64bits**" and it still marks the same error, could you help me with this problem?
[image]

**ODAC 11.2**

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/install112030-1440546.html

Comment: This might be helpful (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4619327/12511801)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/4619327/12511801].

Comment: hi @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes This does not affect other applications that are published in the IIS?

Comment: You ask the same question again and again: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667959/error-opening-oracle-connection-on-server-ora-3134, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741601/problem-replacing-a-reference-in-visual-studio-asp-net, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321575/problema-al-reemplazar-una-referencia-en-visual-studio-asp-net, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320518/error-al-abrir-la-conexion-oracle-en-el-servidor-ora-3134.

Comment: I asked already to verify which DLL is actually loaded. Check with `Connection.GetType().Assembly.Location`. Check your GAC (with `gacutil.exe`), perhaps you should remove all Oracle components completely (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client) and install a fresh Oracle Client include Oracle Data Provide for .NET

Comment: @andresmartinez none of the comments and answers in your duplicatd questions solved your problem? if not, **please keep updated 1 question only** *(you can keep 1 question updated in es.stackoverflow too, though)* - explain why those solutions didn't work.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit is there a way to flag such questions for be deleted? - I'm flagging per link, but I think moderators should handle this situation.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes, I closed two out of three. For the Spanish version I don't have sufficient reputation. The open one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741601/problem-replacing-a-reference-in-visual-studio-asp-net

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry but, there were problems that arose, according to the changes from 32 bits to 64

Comment: This one may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client#25412992